# Sinatra streaming app + em::periodic timer at launch

Tags: sinatra, eventmachine

I need to create a streaming webapp with Sinatra, I try to use a single "source" of streaming when i have multiples connections open, what's the best way to do it?

I can't test before fews days but my primary idea is something like this :

```
set :server, :thin
connections = []

configure do
  EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do
    connections.each { |out| out << "test" << "\n" }
  end
end

get '/' do
  stream(:keep_open) { |out| connections << out }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you didn't manage to make it work:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  set :path, '/tmp'
  set :environment, 'production'

  def initialize
    @connections = []

    EM::next_tick do
      EM::add_periodic_timer(1) do
        @connections.each do |out|
          out << "test" << "</br>"
        end
      end
    end

  end

  get '/' do
    stream(:keep_open) do |out|
      @connections << out
    end
  end

end

run MyApp.new
```

I always prefer to use a proper class for sinatra applications, in this case it allows storing the connections without relying on global or pseudo global variables.